# How to make thick line in android programatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

I've tried setting bigger stroke width and all of that but it still doesnt work, here is my code

```
private fun init() {
    paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paint.strokeWidth= 100f
    paint.color = Color.BLACK
}

public override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(start.x,start.y,end.x,end.y,paint)
}
```

Comment: I've not dived into Kotlin quite yet, but I would expect it has similar scope rules to Java. So I would think that the `val paint = Paint()` you've declared and initialized in `init()` is not the same `paint` you're using in `onDraw()`. Remove the `val` from the beginning of that line.

Comment: I completely missed that but the line is still thin

Comment: Please post the complete class.

Comment: Is `init()` called anywhere? Note that it's different from an `init {}` block.

Comment: can you use xml? Because you could just create a View with "any"dp height

Answer (score 0):

Use view. Set view color. Then on view height and view width set one to how long you want. Ie height = match parent width= 4dp